# Seq.map faster than a regular for loop?

Tags: performance, f#

I'm learning F# and one thing that preoccupies me about this language is performance. I've written a small benchmark where I compare idiomatic F# to imperative-style code written in the same language - and much to my surprise, the functional version comes out significantly faster.

The benchmark consists of:

1. Reading in a text file using File.ReadAllLines
2. Reversing the order of characters within each line
3. Writing back the result to the same file using File.WriteAllLines.

Here's the code:

```
open System
open System.IO
open System.Diagnostics

let reverseString(str:string) =
    new string(Array.rev(str.ToCharArray()))

let CSharpStyle() = 
    let lines = File.ReadAllLines("text.txt")
    for i in 0 .. lines.Length - 1 do
        lines.[i] <- reverseString(lines.[i])

    File.WriteAllLines("text.txt", lines)

let FSharpStyle() = 
    File.ReadAllLines("text.txt")
    |> Seq.map reverseString
    |> (fun lines -> File.WriteAllLines("text.txt", lines))

let benchmark func message = 
    // initial call for warm-up
    func()

    let sw = Stopwatch.StartNew()
    for i in 0 .. 19 do
        func()

    printfn message sw.ElapsedMilliseconds


[<EntryPoint>]
let main args = 
    benchmark CSharpStyle "C# time: %d ms"
    benchmark FSharpStyle "F# time: %d ms"
    0
```

Whatever the size of the file, the "F#-style" version completes in around 75% of the time of the "C#-style" version. My question is, why is that? I see no obvious inefficiency in the imperative version.

Comment: Kudos @Dr_Asik for a well prepared question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Seq.map` is different from `Array.map`. Because sequences (`IEnumerable<T>`) are not evaluated until they are enumerated, in the F#-style code no computation actually happens until `File.WriteAllLines` loops through the sequence (not array) generated by `Seq.map`.

In other words, your C#-style version is reversing all the strings and storing the reversed strings in an array, and then looping through the array to write out to the file. The F#-style version is reversing all the strings and writing them more-or-less directly to the file. That means the C#-style code is looping through the entire file three times (read to array, build reversed array, write array to file), while the F#-style code is looping through the entire file only twice (read to array, write reversed lines to file).

You'd get the best performance of all if you used `File.ReadLines` instead of `File.ReadAllLines` combined with `Seq.map` - but your output file would have to be different from your input file, as you'd be writing to output while still reading from input.

Comment: Ah, I see it now - the C# version calls File.WriteAllLines(string, string[]) while the F# version calls File.WriteAllLines(string, IEnumerable<string>). Therefore there are indeed just 2 loops instead of 3. It didn't come to my mind that there were other overloads of that method. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

The *Seq.map* form has several advantages over a regular loop.  It can precompute the function reference just once; it can avoid the variable assignments; and it can use the input sequence length to presize the result array.

Comment: That looks like very valid points, but I have difficulty seeing what you mean. Could you please expand on and illustrate each point a little? Thanks.